# Marginal effect calculation in Stata

Tags: interaction, stata, standard-deviation

My estimated dynamic GMM model results are as follows.

$$Y = -0.009 + 0.009PF + 0.015PS - 0.001(PF\times PS)$$

I want to calculate the marginal effect of $PF$ at $PS$ (min, mean, max), which I can express as follows:

marginal effect of $PF = 0.009 - 0.001 PS$.

I can calculate it manually, but it is time-consuming. Is there any command that calculates the marginal effect after dynamic GMM along with its significance in Stata 12 other than `margins`, or any way that `margins` can work? The `margins` command in Stata does not work after dynamic GMM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `lincom` like this?

```
foreach PS in 10 20 30 {
    lincom _b[PF] + _b[INT]*`PS'
}
```

You would need to alter the values of PS and the name of your interaction variable. You can use the `coeflegend` option in `xtabond` to determine what the coefficients are named.